# Is string::compare reliable to determine alphabetical order?

Tags: c++, string

Simply put, if the input is always in the same case (here, lower case), and if the characters are always ASCII, can one use string::compare to determine reliably the alphabetical order of two strings?

Thus, with `stringA.compare(stringB)` if the result is 0, they are the same, if it is negative, stringA comes before stringB alphabetically , and if it is positive, stringA comes after?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the docs at cplusplus.com,

> The member function returns 0 if all
>   the characters in the compared
>   contents compare equal, a negative
>   value if the first character that does
>   not match compares to less in the
>   object than in the comparing string,
>   and a positive value in the opposite
>   case.

So it will sort strings in ASCII order, which will be alphabetical for English strings (with no diacritical marks or other extended characters) of the same case.

Comment: IIRC, apostrophes and hyphens are not diacritical marks, right?

Comment: Right, they'll sort in ASCII order.

Comment: Generally, when alphabetizing, one does not consider punctuation marks in determining order, so punctuation should be removed from the strings.  In any case, the apostrophe and hyphen are both below the alphabetic ranges in ASCII.

Comment: +1 for mentionning the problem of diacritical marks. `string::compare` only works for the lower ASCII (0-127).

Comment: As @JamesMcNellis has pointed out, it only work for strings of the same case.

Comment: As I said in the answer "of the same case". In ASCII order: ASCII 'A' < ASCII 'a'

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as all of the characters in both strings are of the same case, and as long as both strings consist only of letters, this will work.

`compare` is a member function, though, so you would call it like so:

```
stringA.compare(stringB);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `string` is the instantiation of the template class `basic_string` with the default parameters: `basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >`. The compare function in the `basic_string` template will use the `char_traits<TChar>::compare` function to determine the result value.

For `std::string` the ordering will be that of the default character code for the implementation (compiler) and that is usually ASCII order. If you require a different ordering (say you want to consider { a, á, à, â } as equivalent), you can instantiate a `basic_string` with your own `char_traits<>` implementation. providing a different `compare` function pointer.

Comment: Do you have an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

[yes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/),

> The member function returns 0 if all
>   the characters in the compared
>   contents compare equal, a negative
>   value if the first character that does
>   not match compares to less in the
>   object than in the comparing string,
>   and a positive value in the opposite
>   case.
>
> For string objects, the result of a
>   character comparison depends only on
>   its character code (i.e., **its ASCII
>   code**), so the result has some limited
>   alphabetical or numerical ordering
>   meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The specifications for the C and C++ language guarantee for lexical ordering, 'A' < 'B' < 'C' ... < 'Z'.  The same is true for lowercase.

The ordering for text digits is also guaranteed:  '0' < ... < '9'.

When working with multiple languages, many people create an array of characters.  The array is searched for the character.  Instead of comparing characters, the indices are compared.

Comment: The C++ language standard does _not_ specify an execution character set, and as such, it is not guaranteed by the language standard that the letters will be in such an order and it is thus implementation-dependent.