# Sorting an array of strings in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting

I am trying to accomplish the following task:

List the students in alphabetic order, sorted by last name. 
Do not change the given case of the names.
Do not change the output file format. (Firstname Lastname)
Just print the records in order by last name, i.e.

Annie J

Martin K

Toby L

This sort needs to be true alphabetical (not just the "lexicographical" sort).

The data was read in from a file and passed through a virtual function depending on what course this student was enrolled in. Here's what I have.

```
for (int i = 1; i < numStudents; i++)
{
   if (( list[i] -> getLastname() ) < ( list[i - 1] -> getLastname() ))
   { 
       Student *temp = list[i - 1];
       ist[i - 1] = list[i];
       list[i] = temp;
   }
}
```

I've been working on this for a while now and I'm worried I've gone about this all wrong. Any tips/pointers appreciated!

Comment: You've (basically) implemented the inner loop of a bubble sort. That's not enough to sort anything. Why not use `std::sort`? It also appears that your program is likely to access outside the bounds of your `list` array, which is pretty dangerous too.

Comment: sorry, I am somewhat new to programming and still trying to get a hang of the string functions. I'll take a look! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the algorithm library :(

Comment: Then just expand your loop into a proper sort. Check wikipedia for examples for any number of sorting algorithms.

Comment: Also note that `operator<` will do a lexicographic comparison.  So `"amy"` will compare greater than `"Tom"` because `'a'` (ASCII 97) is greater than `'T'` (ASCII 84).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a struct like:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string m_LastName;
    std::string m_FirstName;
};
```

Now you need to make sure you can handle the case where two person have the same last name. In that case you want to look at the first name.

```
bool NameCompare(const Student &name1, const Student &name2)
{
    if(name1.m_LastName == name2.m_LastName) {
        return name1.m_FirstName < name2.m_FirstName;
    }

    return name1.m_LastName < name2.m_LastName;
```

}

Then just call sort on your list of Student

```
std::list<Student> student_list;
// add some Student to the list
student_list.sort(NameCompare);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string comparison function instead of the less than sign you used here:

```
if (( list[i] -> getLastname() ) < ( list[i - 1] -> getLastname() ))
```

Also here's a similar stackoverflow question (partially)

> [Is string::compare reliable to determine alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854499/is-stringcompare-reliable-to-determine-alphabetical-order)

Comment: string comparison as in string::compare, ie: stringA.compare(stringB)

Answer (score 0):

Try this reference, first you have to declare the size of the array of firstname and lastname using `int z = sizeof(lastname, firstname)/sizeof(lastname[0], firstname[0]);` and using `sort(lastname,lastname+z);` will sort the array of lastname then using loop to print the firstname with the sorted lastname.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string firstname[] = {"Michael", "Patricia", "Joseph", "Elizabeth", "Charles", "Barbara", "Thomas", "Margaret", "Robert", "Sarah"};
string lastname[] = {"Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Brown", "Jones", "Miller", "Davis", "Garcia", "Rodriguez", "Wilson"};

int z = sizeof(lastname, firstname)/sizeof(lastname[0], firstname[0]);

sort(lastname,lastname+z); //Use the start and end like this
for(int y = 0; y < z; y++){
cout << firstname[y]<< " " << lastname[y] << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).